# How can I count the number of words in a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to count how many words there are in a string in SQL.

```
Select  ("Hello To Oracle") from dual;
```

I want to show the number of words. In the given example it would be 3 words though there could be more than one space between words.

Comment: I have used Only pl/sql but many commands . if there is any way in sql, pls let me know

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  Then tell us what happens when you try it so we can help you adjust what you're doing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use something similar to this.  This gets the length of the string, then substracts the length of the string with the spaces removed.  By then adding the number one to that should give you the number of words:

```
Select length(yourCol) - length(replace(yourcol, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bf5b/7)

If you use the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (yourCol varchar2(15))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (yourCol)
         VALUES ('Hello To Oracle')
    INTO yourtable (yourCol)
         VALUES ('oneword')
    INTO yourtable (yourCol)
         VALUES ('two words')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

And the query:

```
Select yourcol,
  length(yourCol) - length(replace(yourcol, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
from yourtable
```

The result is:

```
|         YOURCOL | NUMBOFWORDS |
---------------------------------
| Hello To Oracle |           3 |
|         oneword |           1 |
|       two words |           2 |
```

Comment: it's ok but if there is many spaces between words . it counts it like word. this is wrong the space can not be  word

Comment: how can ignor counting spaces . because if string has spaces between words it count it like words. like this "HELLO             TO ORACLE          " the space counting.

Comment: here the spaces removed from my string\

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using Oracle 11g it's even simpler-

```
select regexp_count(your_column, '[^ ]+') from your_table
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ad5b/1)

Comment: or `select regexp_count(your_column, '[^[:space:]]+') from your_table`

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to remove multiple spaces too, try this:

```
Select length('500  text Oracle Parkway Redwood Shores CA') - length(REGEXP_REPLACE('500  text Oracle Parkway Redwood Shores CA',
'( ){1,}', ''))  NumbofWords
from dual;
```

Since I have used the `dual` table you can test this directly in your own development environment.

Comment: Doesn't work with multiple sets of multiple consecutive spaces, e.g. `500  text Oracle Parkway   Redwood Shores  CA` returns 10.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @List       NVARCHAR(MAX) = '   ab a 
x'; /*Your column/Param*/
DECLARE @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255) = ' ';/*space*/
DECLARE @WordsTable TABLE (Data VARCHAR(1000));

/*convert by XML the string to table*/
INSERT INTO @WordsTable(Data)
SELECT Data = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)')
FROM 
( 
SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
    + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
    + '</i>').query('.')
) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)



/*Your total words*/
select count(*) NumberOfWords
from @WordsTable
where Data is not null;

/*words list*/
select *
from @WordsTable
where Data is not null
```

/*from this Logic you can continue alon*/