# Calculate word length with SQL

Tags: sql

Is it possible to calculate for each word its length with SQL only? For example for the following sentence:

```
I have a length of x.

1  4   1  6     2  1
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products will have different solutions here.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the number of words in a string in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008509/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-oracle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find longest word in string with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502193/find-longest-word-in-string-with-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Can try a custom method to create:

following is a sample code that can help:

```
Declare @products varchar(200) = 'I have a length of x.'
Declare @individual varchar(20) = null
Declare @lengthOfProducts varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %', @products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                    0,
                                    PATINDEX('% %', @products))
        SELECT @individual
        SET @lengthOfProducts = @lengthOfProducts + ' ' + LEN(@individual)

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                  LEN(@individual + ' ') + 1,
                                  LEN(@products))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @products
        SET @products = NULL
        SELECT @lengthOfProducts
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the `LEN()` function. You have just to use this in SQL

```
SELECT LEN(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

and this in Oracle

```
SELECT LENGTH(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Credits : [SQL LEN() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp)

Comment: They want the length of each Word in String.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server, use `LEN(column_name)`. 
For oracle use `LENGTH(column_name)` 
e.g `SELECT CustomerName,LEN(Address) as LengthOfAddress
FROM Customers;`

Comment: They want the length of each Word in String.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008509/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-oracle). Try this link.