# Find longest word in string with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found the following snippet online:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(5000)= 'aaaa bbbbb cccccccc ddddddddddddddddddd'

SELECT TOP 1 Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') as longest_Word
FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@str, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
ORDER  BY Len(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) DESC
```

Which finds the longest word in a text file ('ddddddddddddddddddd in this case). However, I do not know how to apply this per row in a certain column so that it adds a column next to each row which tells me what the longest word is in SQL Server.

Each column in SQL Server in which it needs to search should look like this with the extra column added next to it:

```
COLUMN 1     RESULT
ABC ABCD     ABCD
BC  BCDE     BCDE
9II IIIIV    IIIIV
...          ...
```

Comment: What do you do for ties?

Comment: @SqlZim Good point.  I'll watch for OP's response.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I was just curious. Already upvoted your answer as it will be a minor adjustment regardless of the response.

Answer (score 3):

A simple **CROSS APPLY** can help here.

Note, I used my own XML Parser because it is "XML Safe"

```
Declare @YourTable table ([COLUMN 1] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('ABC ABCD'),
('BC  BCDE'),
('9II IIIIV')

Select A.[COLUMN 1]
      ,Result = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top 1 *
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[COLUMN 1],' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
                 Order by Len(RetVal) Desc,RetSeq
             ) B
```

Returns

```
COLUMN 1    Result
ABC ABCD    ABCD
BC  BCDE    BCDE
9II IIIIV   IIIIV
```

> **EDIT - You Want to Show TIES**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([COLUMN 1] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('ABC ABCD'),
('BC  BCDE 1234'),
('9II IIIIV')

Select A.[COLUMN 1]
      ,Result = B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top 1 with ties *
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[COLUMN 1],' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                       ) B1
                 Order by Dense_Rank() over (Order by Len(RetVal) Desc)
             ) B
```

Returns

```
COLUMN 1        Result
ABC ABCD        ABCD
BC  BCDE 1234   BCDE   --<< Tie 
BC  BCDE 1234   1234   --<< Tie Added for Illustration
9II IIIIV       IIIIV
```

Comment: This looks good. One minor comment is that where the fields contains punctuation such as commas, full-stops and brackets this code will effectively treat them as part of any word they neighbour​. To avoid that, before applying the logic above you could replace each offending punctuation character with a space. Though even that could be awkward with some characters - such as apostrophes which can exist both within and around words.

Comment: @SteveLovell True, but OP did not mention any punctuation.  If that is the case, there are other techniques to "normalize" the string.   For the moment, I'll take it at face value of being space delimited

Comment: Thanks for the help John, however this is still based on an exampe of your own input. I actually would like to apply this to an existing table with an existing column. But replacing @yourtable with my table name does not work and same for column name.

Comment: @Probs No, it it based on an example of your input.  The (at)YourTable is just a table variable and it is demonstrative.   You are simply wrong,  both examples do work.  Since you did provide specifices, we trust that you can  make the necessary adjustments.   There is only one [YourTable] to replace and two [COLUMN 1]'s to replace.